# How to use Powershell to customize "Region and Language" settings in win7 or win2008

Tags: .net, windows-7, powershell, command-line, windows-server-2008-r2

I am new to Powershell and I have searched the internet for whole day but still cannot find out how to customize "Region and Language" settings using Powershell in win7 or win2008.

I want to change the following settings within Powershell:

1. Current System Locale
2. Short Date and Long Date format
3. Short Time and Long Time format
4. Current Location

Anybody knows how to do that using Powershell? Cmd/Bat/.NET solutions also welcome!

Answer (score 6):

I know your question was about Windows 7; this information may be helpful for those now running newer versions. [`Set-WinUserLanguageList`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852168.aspx), [`New-WinUserLanguageList`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852133.aspx) and [`Get-WinUserLanguageList`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852112.aspx) in Windows 8 and up let you control the installed languages. For example to add a language:

```
$list = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$list.Add("fr-FR")
Set-WinUserLanguageList $list
```

[`Set-Culture`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/Library/hh852137.aspx) in PowerShell 3 lets you change culture, for example to choose defaults for Germany:

```
Set-Culture de-DE
```

Or, to set custom formats:

```
$culture = Get-Culture
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = 'dddd, d MMMM yyyy'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = 'h:mm tt'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = 'h:mm:ss tt'
Set-Culture $culture
```

To change the location, use [`Set-WinHomeLocation`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852129.aspx), for example to set the user's location to Austria:

```
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 14
```

MSDN has a [list of GeoIds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374073.aspx) and a TechNet has a reference for [international settings cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852115.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

@bourne lead me to

```
& $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe "intl.cpl,,/f:`"c:\setKeyboardUK.xml`""
```

Note the lack of a space between the ,, and /f, the use of quotes around the whole thing and the back tick to escape the quotes around the path (that are necessary).

This is my setKeyboardUK.xml file

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend"> 
<!--User List-->
<gs:UserList>
    <gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true"/> 
</gs:UserList>
<gs:UserLocale> 
    <gs:Locale Name="en-GB" SetAsCurrent="true"/> 
</gs:UserLocale>
<!--location--> 
<gs:LocationPreferences> 
    <gs:GeoID Value="242"/> 
</gs:LocationPreferences>
<gs:InputPreferences>
    <!--en-GB--> 
    <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0809:00000809" Default="true"/> 
</gs:InputPreferences>
```

To check if the settings are applied(because failures are silent) open Event Viewer and "Application and Services Logs" then "Microsoft", "Windows", "International","Operational" any successful changes or failures are logged here(the logging is enabled by default).

FYI I did all this on Powershell 3 on Windows 2008 R2 64bit. YMMV

Comment: Worked for me. There is a little caveat with the implementation I find, if you run as an admin it will change the default (for new users) but not EXISTING users. If you run as a non-admin user it will change for that user but not for the default. Just keep it in mind when your implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know this is kind of old, but I had to do the same but I did it in a batch script. 
I am now currently trying to figure out how to do it in powershell.

Check out my post here - https://superuser.com/questions/353752/windows-7-change-region-and-language-settings-using-a-script

The same should apply in Powershell using the following command:

```
PS C:\> & $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe "intl.cpl,, /f:path\to\xml\file\change_system_region_to_US.xml"
```

However, for me it doesn't work for some reason even though the 
command executes without error, the changes don't actually take effect.

If you run the same command from a standard CMD window, the changes take effect immediately.
And if you remote the quotations to match the way you would run it in a CMD window you get
the following error:

```
PS C:\> & $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe intl.cpl,, /f:"path\to\xml\file\change_system_region_to_US.xml"
    Missing argument in parameter list.
    At line:1 char:50
    + & $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe intl.cpl,, <<<<  /f:"path\to\xml\file\change_system_region_to_US.xml"
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (,:String) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

Powershell doesn't appear to like the comma's very much.

Doing so in a .bat file though works like a charm. Just make sure you get your country codes and stuff right. It might require a little tinkering to get the .xml file to change the parameters you want.